# Extracting and parsing HTML from a secure website with Python?

Tags: python, ssl, web, extract

Let's dive into this, shall we?

Ok, I need to write a script (I don't care what language, prefer something like Python or Javascript, but whatever works I will take time to learn). The script will access multiple URL's, extract text from each site and store it into a folder on my PC. (From there I am manipulating the data with Python, which I know how to do.)

EDIT:
Currently I am using python's `NLTK` module. Here is a simple version of my code:

```
url  = "<URL HERE>"
html = urlopen(url).read()
raw = nltk.clean_html(html)
print(raw)
```

This code works fine for both **http** and **https**, but not for instances where authentication is required.

Is there a Python module which deals with secure authentication?

Thanks in advance for help! And to the mods who will view this as a bad question, please just give me ways to make it better. I need ideas..from people, not Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mechanize](http://stockrt.github.io/p/emulating-a-browser-in-python-with-mechanize/) ([2](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)) is one option, other is just with urllib2

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look into it. --Looks like it can only handle Basic Authentication though.

Comment: Another option is Selenium

Comment: Python's urllib2 will not work. (Not with my tinkering anyway) The site I am trying to access does not use basic authentication, they use asp. Still have to look into Mechanize..I don't want to simulate a browser session, but if that's the **only** option... _sigh_