# Logging in, navigating, and extracting text on SSL site using Python?

Tags: python, asp.net, authentication, extract, mechanize

### Precursor: I asked a question similar to this yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134834/extracting-and-parsing-html-from-a-secure-website-with-python). My reason for not editing that question is that even though the two are similar, this one is far more advanced.

**My Project**: Using Python, I want to logon to a secure website, navigate to several pages within that session and extract text from those pages into a file.

**The Details**: Here is all the information I have gathered/code I have written.

Here are the portions of the secured site's logon page that are worth noting:

```
<form action="index.asp" method="post" name="form">
   <input type="text" id="user" name="user"">
   <input type="password" name="password">
   <input type="hidden" name="logon" value="username">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" class="button">
</form>
```

There is also javascript code on the page checking for cookies, so I know I'll need `cookielib.CookieJar()`.

### BIG EDIT

I am importing the following modules: `urllib`, `urllib2`, `cookielib` and `nltk`.

To produce the following code:

```
cookiejar = cookielib.CookieJar()

# Notice I set 'debug' to 'true'.
debug = True
handlers = [
                urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=debug),
                urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=debug),
                urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar),
           ]
opener = urllib2.build_opener(*handlers)
# These headers I copied directly from Chrome's Developer Tools
opener.addheaders = [
    ("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"),
    ("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch"),
    ("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8"),
    ("Cache-Control", "max-age=0"),
    ("Connection", "keep-alive"),
    ("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
    ("Host", "www.myebill.com"),
    ("Origin", "https://www.myebill.com"),
    ("Referer", "https://www.myebill.com/index.asp?startnam"),
    ("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36")
                    ]
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# Passing the form data as a URL-encoded string
payload = "user=<User>&password=<Password>&logon=username&submit=Log+In"

req = urllib2.Request("https://www.myebill.com/index.asp", data=payload)
cookiejar.add_cookie_header(req)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
pdata = page.read()

print( nltk.clean_html( pdata ) )
```

**NOTE**: If you would like me to post the debug output, just ask. :)

**My Problem**: After running my code, I *still* get a "Your session has either timed out or you have not logged on correctly." message.

Help please? I tried learning mechanize, but it seems the only documentation I can find online is convoluted and confusing. Any suggestions or code would be appreciated.

Also, when I do find the answer, I promise to post my complete code as an edit to anyone who needs this as a reference! (omitting logon information, of course..)

Comment: Using your browser's request monitor will help a lot. Log in with your browser and compare that request with the one sent by Python. You're probably missing a hidden field.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @Blender! I used Chrome's Developer tools to capture a session of logging on and off. There was some useful information that I was omitting, but adding to the code still did not yield the correct result. But I know I am closer!

Comment: You are not correctly encoding the URL parameters - put the required parameters within a dictionary and then use urllib.urlencode(parameters_dict) to encode the values. Here parameter_dict is the dictionary storing the parameter values

Comment: Thanks for catching that, although when I made the correction it still did not work. You can see my posted answer for how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys, but I did finally solve the problem using Python's module `Requests`.

Here is the code:

```
import nltk
from requests import session

payload = {
    'user': '<Username>',
    'password': '<Password>',
    'logon': 'username',
    'submit': 'Log In'
}

headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://www.myebill.com/index.asp?startnam',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36'
    }

with session() as c:
    c.post('https://www.myebill.com/index.asp?startnam', data=payload, headers=headers)
    request = c.get('https://www.myebill.com/index.asp')
    print request.headers
    print( nltk.clean_html( request.text ) )
```

For anyone who will use this code, just remember to monitor your login session with program of your choice (e.g. Wireshark, Chrome Developer Tools, Firefox Firebug, etc.) and replace the "payload" dictionary with data from your session.

Thanks again for the help! Maybe one day I will look more into the `urllib` and `urllib2` method, but if `Requests` performs the same operation with shorter, simpler code... **Yeah!!!**

Answer (score 1):

I will attempt a shot at this. Firstly, as per the HTML form code snippet posted, the form performs  POST action to a GET URL `https://www.myebill.com/index.asp?nam`. You may want to confirm once again that this is the URL you indeed want to POST to.

Having said that, urllib2 already supports an HTTPSHandler. There is a related Stack Overflow discussion on how to access web services over using Python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082128/how-do-i-authenticate-a-urllib2-script-in-order-to-access-https-web-services-fro). While, this is not directly related to the query - the answer to this question contains good pointers about what care should be taken when we are attempting to logon using HTTPS via a program. Most specifically, it is the setting of the **Referer** tag within the header. This is necessary, since secure websites use this mechanism to protect themselves from a CSRF attack.

The below code snipet shows the **most important** settings that you would need to put in place prior to making a request. I got this from the [Nullege Python for Simple Dropbox Login](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@s@i@simpledropbox-0.2.2@simpledropbox@__init__.py/105/urllib2.HTTPSHandler/python)

```
handlers = [
                urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=debug),
                urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=debug),
                urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookiejar),
            ]
opener = urllib2.build_opener(*handlers)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)   #the opener will be used for all urlopen requests from now on.
```

Note the use of the HTTPSHandler.

You then fill in the authentication information:

```
payload = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'j_password' : password})
```

and then perform a login:

```
headers['Referer'] = self.urlbase #note the presence of the "Referer' header
req = urllib2.Request(url=self.urlbase+'login', data=data, headers=headers)
cookiejar.add_cookie_header(req)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
pdata = page.read()
```

I hope this gives you an idea on how to go about..

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, @Prahalad! I used your sources and the code you posted to create a new script. The new script isn't logging in, but I think it's close. Please see my **edited** question for details.

Comment: @Jacob-IT You should use urllib.urlencode(parameters) to encode the data being sent. Also,